# How to put treeview inside my CGrid

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii

I have table with `acts` and `parent_acts`

I need to make CGridView to look like:

```
Parent_act 1 
  -childact1.1
  -childact1.2  
Parent_act 2
  -childact2
...
```

I have already `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` that shows all parent_acts, but I don't know how to show their children on the same page. I made SQL query, controller action, but dunno what to do with view...

I created `actionAjaxFillTree` in the controller, but how to call it from the `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView`?

Comment: Do you mean that the number of colums will vary after the number of children ?

Comment: Just want to show all children and their parents on the same page as some kind of tree inside CGridView...

Comment: You want something like treegrid?

Comment: Yes, I would like treegrid inside CGrid...Is it possible?

Comment: At current grid implementation it is not possible. You would have to extend grid and add this functionality by your self, or use [some different solution](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php)